# Execute script in sh mode instead of bash in Shell

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, console

I added my script called `mylovelyscript.sh` to `/bin/` folder. My script contains code that `echo`s text with different text colors. But when I run my script like

```
$ mylovelyscript
```

it executes in bash mode. So, my script give an output with the texts with color codes, like

```
\e[93mHello World!
```

but not colored texts. But when I run my script like `$ sh mylovelyscript.sh` with `sh` command, it executes like how I want. Now, I want my script to give me colored texts like in `sh` mode, but in this case I want to call my script like `$ mylovelyscript`, not like `$ sh mylovelyscript`. How can I do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this line at the beginning of the file:

`#!/bin/sh`

or:

`#!/bin/dash`

Comment: Thanks @Wutaz! I think that it will work. I have a one problem, not related with this problem: I switched to sh mode, as you said, but know I need to change `bash` code to `sh` code, as `sh` can't read `bash style` code.

Comment: Didn't you say you were running it with `sh`?

Comment: no, I was running it with bash, I need to do it on `sh`, in my script there is for...loop which I wrote for `bash`, I need to change it for `sh` mode.

Comment: is there any way to do it in `bash` mode? To make colored texts in bash mode?

Comment: You said you ran it with `$ sh mylovelyscript.sh`.

Comment: yes, but  it is interesting to me, is there any way to do it in bash?

Comment: That's a different question. Right now I'm wondering why you need to port the script when you already ran it successfully with `sh`.

Comment: Because my hashbang was `.../bash` not `.../sh`, so when I ran it, it showed me the text compiled with `bash` not `sh`. It only worked successfully when I ran it with sh command, so I needed to change it to `sh` mode to run it, like typing only script name.