# Execute a statement /bin/bash seems not to work in Virtualbox client

Tags: command-line, bash, virtualbox, python

I do not know if AskUbuntu is the correct place to ask or Stack Overflow.

To execute a statement in Windows use : `C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe` What is the equivalent in Ubuntu? I thought it was : `/bin/bash` but that does not work for me. I tried `/bin/sh` and `/bin/dash` ( like shown [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426694/execute-script-in-sh-mode-instead-of-bash-in-shell) )but without result.

In Virtualbox client I want to be able to execute a statement. For this I use [pyvbox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvbox/0.1.5) which is a Python shell for the virtualbox API.

After installing execute in statement in Virtualbox Windows client is possible with the statement :

```
process, stdout, stderr = gs.execute('C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe', ['/C', 'tasklist'])
```

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21324153/how-to-read-files-from-a-virtual-machine-using-python)

I want to something like this for VBox Ubuntu client with the statement :

```
process, stdout, stderr = gs.execute('/bin/bash',['echo hello world'])
```

which returns no output.

In VBox Ubuntu client statement :

```
which bash
```

returns :

```
/bin/bash
```

And `echo hello world` is executed well.

Which alternatives there might be to execute a statement in Ubuntu? Sorry if this is not the correct place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`man bash`

... i.e. try to adapt your code to `bash -c 'echo Hello!'`

Need to know more about bash?

http://tldp.org has at least two guides om bash - they will take you from a novice to an advanced level.

Comment: Thanks. I tried which raised an exception : 'Specified file was not found on guest'

Comment: I interpret that as a problem caused by pyvbox - try `process, stdout, stderr = gs.execute('/bin/bash',['-c echo hello world'])` or something similar, I suspect the first arg must be kept as is. The bare bash -c call above works. Try it out.

Comment: @Hanna. Very warm. Your suggestion did not work. But  process, stdout, stderr = gs.execute('/bin/bash',['-c', 'echo hello world']) did. Thanks very much.